# How to deploy VuePress on a shared host?

Tags: web-deployment, shared-hosting, vuepress

Can someone tell me how I can deploy (=put in production) my local VuePress site?

If I correctly understand https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/deploy.html, we can't deploy VuePress on our shared host?

If this is true, are there alternatives like using a tool to "convert" the VuePress site to a static site?

Thanks a lot!

Christophe

Answer (score 3):

So simple...

By running `npm run build`, we get a folder called `.vuepress\dist` where everything has been converted to `.html` files.

We just need to copy all these files onto our FTP folder and tadaaa...

Damned, why I hadn't seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one?
https://github.com/jenkey2011/vuepress-deploy
A GitHub Action to build and deploy Vuepress sites to GitHub Pages.And you can set a CNAME file.